# Json parse to variables

Tags: json, parsing

Does Someone can help me to extract lat and long as variables from this?

```
url     : http://something.com/rest/items/location1?type=json
data    : {}
```

'url' output this result

```
{"type":"LocationItem","name":"location1","state":"9.4702741,-76.5070072","link":"http://something/rest/items/location1"},
```

Comment: What language are you using to parse the JSON?

Comment: These variables are inside javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's already a json object being returned - no parsing needed. You would just have to split state on a comma and get the two lat/long pieces. Take this for example:

```
var myOutput = {"type":"LocationItem","name":"location1","state":"9.4702741,-76.5070072","link":"http://something/rest/items/location1"};
var state = myOutput.state;
var splitState = state.split(',');
var latitude = splitState[0];
var longitude = splitState[1];
console.log("Latitude: " + latitude);
console.log("Longitude: " + longitude);
```